# How can I find extended controls button in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I want to change location at Android Studio emulator. but there is no extended controls button. how can I find it?

[screenshot : no extended controls button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nMjuF.png)

Answer (score 0):

File -> Settings -> Emulator -> Launch in a tool window (unchecking)

than you can see extended controls button